# File got by AssetManager is not the original one

Tags: android, android-ndk

```
AssetManager.openFd(file).createInputStream().getFD()
```

I got a file descriptor from above code. Then I pass it to native API.

```
struct stat s;
size_t size;
fstat(fd, &s);
size = s.st_size;

begin_position = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)
```

I use some C function to describe the FD.

Result shows size is larger than that of the raw file and begin_position is not zero even if I havn't read any bytes before.

It indicates this FD points at the container which contains the original file. Is my conjecture right? And can anyone provide more information about how android deal with the asset files.

Comment: Assets are not unpacked from the APK file, so the file descriptor would be to the asset's entry in the APK itself (which is a ZIP-style archive).

Comment: @CommonsWare Yeah, to avoid being compressed I rename the file to file.png. In such way I can get a normal FD or it will log error "can't get FD from a compressed file"

Comment: You can also use `aaptOptions { noCompress 'pdf', 'mp4', 'ogg' }` (or whatever file extensions you want) in your module's `build.gradle` file to block compression.